# Difference between import appname.models and from appname.models.ModelName in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-import

As a programming style, I find it more useful to write the following:

```
import appname.models 
obj = appname.models.ModelName.objects.filter(status=1)
```

However, I find lot of code written where only the `ModelName` is imported:

```
from appname.models import ModelName
obj = ModelName.objects.filter(status=1)
```

However, I often come across the scenario, where the change in the `ModelName` result in the application breaking and we need to make changes everywhere.

Also, from a readability perspective, the second approach, I find it very difficult know, where was the model defined(which app).

I have been insisting my team to go with the first approach. Wanted to hear your thoughts which is the best approach from the following perspective:

1. Readability
2. Scalability
3. Performance

I really appreciate all your thoughts here.

Comment: There is no difference. Personally I prefer the latter since it has less noise.

Answer (score 0):

```
from appname.models import ModelName
```

I prefer this one becuase this way tell us more clearly about model and model comes from which apps. When u are working of big project using api or Thiry party apps and lots of importing models or other party apps so it difficult to find models or some other stuff. In short way i prefer this one

Answer (score 0):

```
import appname.models
```

> This method is not preferred. Because it adds nothing to code base. You have to use`appname.models` again and again. Code quality will be compromised and loading time will also increase in bigger apps.

```
from appname.models import ModelName
```

> While this approach is more appropriate and efficient as well. You will be importing the Specified model only once  and will be using it again and again.
> This approach is efficient in memory and in loading time as well.